# java reverse string space should be at the same place

Tags: java

I tried this code reverse string space should be at the same place, this code taking input but output not printing not getting error also i'm trying to print output like this

input: java string
output:gnir tsavaj

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    char arr1[]=str.toCharArray();
    char arr2[]=new char[arr1.length];
    for(int i=0;i<=arr1.length-1;i++)
    {
       if(arr1[i]==' ')
       {
           arr2[i]=arr1[i];
       }
   
       for(int j=0;j<=arr1.length-1;j++)
        {
            if(arr2[i]!=' ')
            {
             if(arr2[j]==' ')
            {
                 j--;
            }
            arr2[j]=arr1[i];
            j--;
            }
        }
   }
   str=new String(arr2);
   System.out.print(str);

   }
}
```

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: Your 2nd inner loop is an endless loop: the `j++` would advance `j`, but in the loop body you do `j--` and hence keep looking at the same first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,hope it helps

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter String");
   String str=sc.nextLine();
   char arr1[]=str.toCharArray();
   char arr2[]=new char[arr1.length];
   for(int i=0;i<=arr1.length-1;i++)
   {
       if(arr1[i]==' ')
       {
           arr2[i]=arr1[i];
       }
   }
   int j=arr2.length-1;
   for(int i=0;i<=arr1.length-1;i++)
   {
       if(arr2[i]!=' ')
       {
           if(arr2[j]==' ')
           {
               j--;
           }
           arr2[j]=arr1[i];
           j--;
       }
   }
   str=new String(arr2);
   System.out.print(str);

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just loop your string backwards and add each string to new String.

Below code might help you .

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Main
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    String revstr="";
    
    int j = 0;
     
     for (int i=str.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
     {
         revstr+= str.charAt(i); 
     }
     
   System.out.print(revstr);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please let know is there any mistake in my code...